# Ignoring All Applications That Have Certain Attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query to find all applications that don't trigger certain rules. Each rule triggered is logged in a separate line tied to the application ID.

Data looks like this:

```
ID  RuleNumber

2   1
2   2
2   3
3   2
3   3
4   1
4   5
```

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT ID,RuleNumber FROM Table WHERE RuleNumber not in (2,3)
```

But that just returns the lines that don't have those rule numbers. I want it to skip any ID's that have one of those RuleNumbers attached to them, so my result here should be the lines associated with ID 4.

Comment: You question is unclear.  You say you don't want to skip any IDs but then say your result should only be ID 4 lines. Do you want all IDs to show, with IDs 2 and 3 having NULL RuleNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ID
FROM    Table T1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT 1
                     FROM   Table T2
                     WHERE  T1.ID = T2.ID
                     AND    T2.RuleNumber IN (2,3)
                   );
```

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23296985)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. I am new to stack overflow as a contributor. But when I browse around I see solutions to both easy and tough codes (which is relative to one’s expertise anyways) all over the forum by even users with high reputation. That is really confusing as the answers which offered only some hints didn’t seem to be the best answer or got upvoted, but the ones with an actual solution did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to find the ids that trigger the rule, then use that to exclude those ids...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
  FROM Table
 WHERE ID NOT IN
 (
  SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE RuleNumber IN (2,3)
 )
```

Comment: You can not use an alias name for the NOT IN clause. It will throw an error.

Comment: @san: the query in this answer is not using any column alias

Comment: I was talking about the last line: ) AS excluded

Comment: This worked if I removed the AS excluded at the end.